# jQueryMobile - How to generate dynamic pages for this offline app

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm making a mobile app with jQueryMobile.
The app will show info about an educational institute,
like: details about every person working in the institute,
about every course, etc. For every item mentioned,
the app will show its related info on a new page (screen).

Since there could be hundred of pages due the amount of categories,
I need to know what would be the options for generating pages
on the fly.

The first thing that comes to mind, is doing something like the following:

Given a JSON object like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Paul",
            "image": "http://images1.wer.nocookie.net/Paul.jpg",
            "content": "<p> Paul is the bla bla that <a href=\"/wiki/PAULO\" title=\"PAULO\">PAULO</a> gives to blabla.</p>"
        },
        {
            "name": "Dr. Larry",
            "image": "http://images2.wer.nocookie.net/DRLarry.jpg",
            "content": "<p>Dr. Lawrence (Larry) is a psychologist blabla.</p>"
        }
    ]
}
```

I process it with jQueryMobile this way:

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforeshow', '#home', function(){      
                $.ajax({
                    url: "cast.json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        ajax.parseJSON(result);
                    }
                });         
            });
            var ajax = {  
                parseJSON:function(result){
                    $('#contenido').append('<h1>'+result.data[1].name+'</h1><h2>' + result.data[1].content+ '</h2> <img alt="dsdsd" src="'+result.data[1].image+'">');
                }
            }
```

for this page:

```
<body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home" data-add-back-btn="true">
            <div data-role="header" >
                <h1>This is the header
            </div>  

            <div data-role="content">
                <div id="contenido"></div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
```

But I don't even know if this is a good approach.
What would be a good solution in your opinion?

I want to make the app with PhoneGap.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah,...whats wrong with this?? Seems fine

Comment: hi KyleK, I just wonder if someone know a better way to make pages dinamically. Maybe there is a better way to do this with jQueryMobile.

Comment: Yeah I use jqMobi, http://www.jqmobi.com/   its freakin awesome...so many people think some of my apps are native iPhone apps......theres also a styler for it, which saves so much time.....they didn't use to have that.... http://app-framework-software.intel.com/style.php    Theres also Sencha, which i haven't used as much

Comment: You can see demos of it by googling 'jqMobi kitchen sink'

Comment: This is a demo on how to create pages dynamically without any plugins I hope this is what u r looking for http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/9jc8Y/